# Auto Categorization of Expenses

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a way to automate the categorization of a running list of expenditures.

So in column `B` I have expenses listed (auto imported directly from financial institutions) and in column `C` I have a data validation drop down.
Is there a good way to auto populate the category drop down in Column `C` for some of the more common items in Column `B`?

For instance:
if Column `B` contains the text "transfer to", fill corresponding cell in column `C` with the drop down "Transfers". Or if Column `B` contains the text "Paycheck", fill corresponding cell in column `C` with "Income".

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description on your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].